# Transfer Byte[] Array from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

We are downloading a word document in our controller class as bytes and we wanted to pass the byte array to the view and then open the word docoument using Javascript FileSystemObject and Active X Object (Word).

I'm not sure how to pass the byte array to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an action method that returns `return File(byte[]);` and write you JavaScript to target that new URL.

To pass byte array to the view, just use `return View(byte[])` in your controller action method.

Comment: I need to parse the byte in the View and open the word document in javascript. can you please share some light?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileStreamResult`:

```
public FileStreamResult MyView() {

    byte[] bytearr;
    MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(bytearr);

    return File(m, "mime", "filename");   
}
```

Or you could write a custom `ActionResult` like this:

```
public ActionResult MyView() {
    byte[] bytearr;
    MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(bytearr)
    return new MemoryStreamResult(m, "mime", bytearr.Length, "filename");
}


public class MemoryStreamResult : ActionResult
{
    private MemoryStream _stream;
    private string _fileName;
    private string _contentType;
    private string _contentLength;



    public MemoryStreamResult(MemoryStream stream, string contentType, string contentLength, string fileName = "none")
    {
         this._stream = stream;
         this._fileName = fileName;
         this._contentType = contentType;
         this._contentLength = contentLength;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
         context.HttpContext.Response.Buffer = false;
         context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
         context.HttpContext.Response.ClearContent();
         context.HttpContext.Response.ClearHeaders();

         context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", this._fileName));

         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this._contentLength))
            context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-length", this._contentLength);

         context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = this._contentType;

         this._stream.WriteTo(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream);
         this._stream.Close();

         context.HttpContext.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to handle this on the view side? how to parse the byte on the view and open the word document? I wnated to follow this approach.public FileStreamResult MyView() {

    byte[] bytearr;
    MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(bytearr);

    return File(m, "mime", "filename");   
}

Comment: You don't have to it's returning the content to the browser as the given mime type.

Comment: So you are saying that this will automatically popup the word document in the browser?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I am saying

Comment: cool. But we have a requirement that the document should be saved on the user desktop automatically and opend for edit from desktop.

Comment: So you're going to have to pass the byte[] raw into the view into some client script that does that.

Comment: Yes. That's what we are trying now.. but don't know how to handle the raw bytes on the client side... can you share some sample code for this scenario?

Comment: why wouldnt you just pass a byte[] property in your view model?

Comment: I can but the Fileysystemobject we are using to write the file in user desktop is not accecpting byte as input. Please refer the below link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711216(v=vs.71).aspx